# Small deviation in label tag

Tags: positioning, labels

I have a problem using my current template. The label of the image seems a bit off to the right, but I can't find the fault, can anyone help me? Blue line is the centre of the document.

[image]

This is a small example of my latex document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{smfart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,url,xspace,smfthm}
\usepackage{subfig,epsfig,tikz,float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{pink}{rgb}{0.98,0,0.42}
\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  %keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{pink},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}} % Números romanos en mayúscula 

\tolerance 400
\pretolerance 200

\title[Template]{DOCUMENTO DE PROYECTO}
\date {\today}
\author[J.C.]{Jonathan}
\address{Colegio Litterator}
\email{jonathan.carrero@colegiolitterator.com} 

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Blah, blah, blah
\end{abstract}
\maketitle

\section{Descripción del proyecto}
Blah, blah, blah

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{images/ataque.png}

\caption{Example pic}\label{Fig:example}
\vspace*{-1em}
\end{figure}

Blah, blah, blah

%\bibliographystyle{siam}
% Bibliografía
%\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

In other template types I don't get this, so I assume it's the template configuration. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Different left and right margins, maybe?

Comment: @Sigur how could I do that? Sry I´m kinda newbie using Latex

Comment: Well, I have no access to the class `smfart`, so maybe it is loading different geometries on left and right margins. Usually, two sided documents have different margins so you can print on both sides accordingly.